Getting the following error on my AWS Glue job: pyWriteDynamicFrame. Connection property specified more than once: DB
I created my first visual Glue job.  When I run it I get the error: pyWriteDynamicFrame. Connection property specified more than once: DB.
I looked through the script, I don't see "DB" mentioned anywhere in relation to Snowflake.  Any help/thoughts would be appreciated.




Unrelated rant: Almost 20 years Microsoft created SSIS.  It had a good visual interface.  AWS Glue's interface is... I guess looks like it's 25+ years old?  Does AWS not have a couple of mill hanging around to have someone create a functional UI?

Hi - if you updated your question with the script (and any other relevant information) then you may get a better response to your question

Someone on my team found the issue.  The connection we were using had the database listed and the visual glue job had the database listed as well.
